# Karate: How to set particular steps to run only once before any of the scenarios in a feature?

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Is there a way in Karate automation framework to do something similar to @BeforeAll in Junit?
I have a service that enriches given elasticsearch index with some data. I need to call it only once and then to have different scenarios that test different documents from that ES index.

I tried with karate.setupOnce, but this method shold be called in each scenario and it brings only confusions. My setup scenarios does not store any data to be used in the other scenarios.